# overflow-x not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am having issues with `overflow-x:hidden` in IE. All other browsers seem to accept it, but IE creates `overflow-x:hidden` (x and y).

Does anyone have any tips on a IE fix?

Comment: worked it out:  -ms-overflow-x

Comment: this must be a misunderstanding. IE has supported `overflow-x` since version 5. The synonym `-ms-overflow-x` was added in version 8, but it should not be used. You must have done something else that actually changed the situation.

Comment: This provides a good detailed description of "-ms-overflow-style":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style

Answer (score -6, accepted):

yah overflow-x and y is a css3 specification.

Try using a jquery plugin like http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

otherwise I'm guessing you are trying to hide the "width" of the element? why not
1. set the width of the element to a specific size
2. set overflow:hidden
3. set height to auto

Comment: No need to. The property is well supported, including IE 5+: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-x

Comment: this is my doc type..   `<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: any answer which says 'use this jquery plugin' should be banned

Answer (score 8):

Since -ms-overflow-x is working it's possible you have an issue with your DOCTYPE declaration.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Remarks
>
> Windows Internet Explorer 8. The -ms-overflow-x attribute is an
>   extension to CSS, and can be used as a synonym for overflow-x in IE8
>   Standards mode.
>
> With Microsoft Internet Explorer 6 and later, when you use the
>   !DOCTYPE declaration to specify standards-compliant mode, this
>   property applies to the html object.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the same issue I was having in IE8 by adding:

```
    position: relative;
```

to the div that needed the overflow-x: hidden functionality.

Without the relative positioning on the div, my content was showing outside the div even though I had set overflow-x: hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of **Svbaker** is also correct. try this one this work for me.

```
    <div style="overflow: auto;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
                position:relative;
                ">
                 ...somecodes..
    </div>
```

-ms-overflow-y: hidden; - this works for IE8 just remember adding position:relative because overflow-y/x is for CSS3 and works for higher browser.